# How can I simply change a class variable from another class in ObjectiveC?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I simply want to change a variable of an object from another class. I can compile without a problem, but my variable always is set to 'null'.
I used the following code:

Object.h:

```
@interface Object : NSObject {
    //...
    NSString *color;
    //...
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString* color;

+ (id)Object;
- (void)setColor:(NSString*)col;
- (NSString*)getColor;
@end
```

Object.m:

```
+(id)Object{
    return [[[Object alloc] init] autorelease];
}

- (void)setColor:(NSString*)col {
    self.color = col;
}

- (NSString*)getColor {
    return self.color;
}
```

MyViewController.h

```
#import "Object.h"

@interface ClassesTestViewController : UIViewController {
    Object *myObject;
    UILabel *label1;
}

@property UILabel *label1;
@property (assign) Object *myObject;
@end
```

MyViewController.m:

```
#import "Object.h"
@implementation MyViewController
@synthesize myObject;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [myObject setColor:@"red"];
    NSLog(@"Color = %@", [myObject getColor]);
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

The NSLog message is always `Color = (null)`

I tried many different ways to solve this problem, but no success.
Any help would be appreciated.

---

Thanks for the help so far.

I modified the code as follow, but it still doesn't work as it should.

```
MyViewController.h:
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "Object.h"

    @interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
        Object *myObject;
    }
    @property (nonatomic, retain) Object *myObject;
    @end
```

MyViewController.m:

```
#import "MyViewController.h"
#import "Object.h"

@implementation MyViewController
@synthesize myObject;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
Object *myObject = [Object new];
myObject = 0;
[myObject setColor:@"red"];
NSLog(@"color = %@", myObject.color);
[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

If I do it like this, NSLog returns `color = null` (and I think `myObject` is only visible in viewDidLoad). How can declare `myObject` and make it visible in MyViewController?
I stripped down my Object class to

Object.h:

```
@interface Object : NSObject {
    NSString *color;
}    
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *color;
@end
```

Object.m:

```
#import "Object.h"
@implementation Object
@synthesize color;
@end
```

I wasn't able to define an object `myObject` in ViewDidLoad so that I can access its properties from the whole ViewController class? What did I miss?
Side question: Why do I have to set myObject to 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You're declaring a property, then explicitly declaring the accessors in Object.h. You only need to do one or the other - they mean the same thing (well, almost - you'll have `color` instead of `getColor`)
2. To implement the property in Object.m you should use `@synthesize color`. The explicit implementations, again, are then redundant (unless they do anything extra).
3. The explicit `setColor` implementation in Object.m is calling the property - which you are implementing explicitly, so I would have expected you to get an infinite recursion here.
4. MyViewController.m should probably synthesize `label1`, since you declare the property in the header (although it's not being used in your snippet).
5. [myObject getColor] is calling the color property, which you declared but did not synthesize. If you had explicitly implemented it as `color` it would have picked that up - but it won't match `getColor` (which is fortunately as that would have led to an infinite recursion again.
6. I don't see anywhere where you create your myObject instance. If you don't it will be `nil` and methods called on it (including property accesses) will return 0 or nil.

I suspect (6) is the cause of your issue, but the others need to be addressed too. Make sure you read up on property syntax.

Comment: And the use of `@synthesize myObject;` suggests a misunderstanding about creating object instances vs. synthesizing property accessors. +1 for the idea of reading up on property syntax.

Comment: ...and here's a link to the reference: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html

Comment: It's also generally a bad idea to begin a method name with a capital letter, as you've done with the +Object method.